# Variable dentro del IF imprime vacio

Tags: bash

Estoy intentando crear un script en bash pero no se cual es el problema, todo funciona bien cuando quiero generar un archivo con toda la información de las variables, con excepcion de la variable **APPID**

Ya intente incializar la variable APPID = 0, poner **echo APPID** dentro del IF, sin embargo la variable no se imprime

```
#!/bin/bash

CUSTOMERTRUNKID=$2
IP=${SSAPPSIPPORT_ARRAY[0]}
PORT=${SSAPPSIPPORT_ARRAY[1]}
SESSIONID=$3

if [[ $IP == "192.168.170.70" ]];
then
if [[ $PORT == "30000" ]];
    then
            APPID = "1"
            exit 1;
    fi
    if [[ $PORT == "30010" ]];
    then
            APPID = "2"
            exit 1;
    fi
fi

echo 1,$CUSTOMERTRUNKID,$SESSIONID,$APPID >> $PATH$FILENAME
echo 2,$CARRIERTRUNKID,$SESSIONID,$APPID >> $PATH$FILENAME
```

El resultado en el archivo esta bien pero en la última coma deberia ir el valor APPID pero no se imprime

```
1,2212,01677859971001855790,
2,T2212,01677859971001855790,
```

Comment: Ya intentaste cambiando el nombre de la variable, por otra ?? Igual y puede ser alguna palabra reservada.

Comment: Si pero no funcionó, lo que hice fue porner en cada IF

echo 1,$CUSTOMERTRUNKID,$SESSIONID,$APPID >> $PATH$FILENAME
echo 2,$CARRIERTRUNKID,$SESSIONID,$APPID >> $PATH$FILENAME

Answer (score 1):

1. La variable `APPID` sólo tomará un valor si el puerto es 30000 o 30010 y la IP es 192.168.170.70. En cualquier otro caso, queda vacía.
2. Si no te está saliendo un mensaje del estilo `bash: orden APPID no encontrada`, quiere decir que ninguno de los casos anteriores está sucediendo, porque tienes un espacio antes del signo de igual en `APPID = "1"`. Para asignar la variable debes utilizar `APPID="1"`. Verifica si `IP` y `PORT` realmente tienen los valores que esperas.
3. En general te conviene usar comillas dobles cuando utilices los valores de las variables, por ejemplo `echo "$APPID"` para evitar efectos no deseados, especialmente cuando lo que se pone en la variable viene del exterior.

Answer (score 1):

Bash respeta los espacios. Es decir, no es lo mismo `APPID=1` que `APPID = 1`.
El primero, setea a la variable; en el segundo, `APPID` es buscado como comando.